# Using colours in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scatter-plot

Using the following code generates this plot

```
ggplot(df_44, aes(x = latest_tli_date, y = farmer_created_at, fill = ward_id)) +
  geom_point()+ scale_color_brewer(palette = "BuPu")
```

I need the 4 wards to have different colours. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you are using the default shape (i.e. `shape = 19`) in `geom_point()`, it doesn't really have a "fill" aesthetic (because by default, it's a filled circle with black colour). Therefore, you'll need to use a colour aesthetic to colour it, or choose another shape (21 - 25) that can be filled.

Answer (score 2):

try using the fill argument in the `geom_point` function

**Edit**: I just tried an example code, the fill and col arguments is going to color it with on a continuous scale because the data is continuous.

If you factor your value you want to color, it should color it discretely.

```
ggplot(df_44, aes(x = latest_tli_date, y = farmer_created_at)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(ward_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `colour` aesthetics:
If `ward_id` is numeric then you might want to replace by colour = factor(ward_id):

Have a look here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_44, aes(x = latest_tli_date, y = farmer_created_at, colour = ward_id)) +
  geom_point()+ scale_color_brewer(palette = "BuPu")
```